# Injected Javascript not overriding URL in UiWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In the process of injecting a local .js file into an external page hosted from another server in UIWebView.

While I am new, I feel the following code should render a remote HTML page and override it with the local js. file. In reality it just loads the page with no js.

My **ViewController.m**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    //load url into webview
    NSString *strURL = @"http://localhost:9080/test/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.viewWeb loadRequest:urlRequest];

    NSString *js = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"script" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@"www" ];
    [self.viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];

}
```

The .js file (**script.js**) is injecting a .css file (**style.css**) into the header of the external html page:

```
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = "style.css";
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```

The HTML of the external page (**index.html**) is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<div class="big">TEXT</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the files are located in the `www` directory where the folder was imported into Xcode as **"copy with create folder references"**.

Outside of the Xcode project it all works if I place the .js, .html, .css in one folder. But once I launch the simulator its a no go. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What have you done to make certain the javascript is loading correctly into the variable `js`?  Have you NSLogged it or set a breakpoint?  You're certainly not using an error variable and checking it to make sure everything went fine...

Comment: Outside, if all three files are in the same folder they work. But not sure what you mean about NSLogged or breakpoint. Xcode does not show any errors after compile.

Comment: This line: `NSString *js = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];`  The method takes an argument of type `NSError **`.  You're not bothering with it.  You're not setting a breakpoint after this line and checking `js`, and you're not doing `NSLog(@"%@",js);` so how do you know the Javascript file is being successfully read?

Comment: Hi i see what you are talking about, I removed that set of code. Since I did not understand that part of the code.

Comment: ... are you kidding me? You code did look mostly right, now it looks entirely wrong.  Please post the code you're ACTUALLY using.  Before you make an edit here, make it in your IDE and try compiling it and running it and see what difference that makes...

Comment: @nhgrif hi I'm sorry but it complied fine in my IDE and that is a copy and paste and still no luck. You do not have to help me if you think this is a waste of your time, but please do not bash on someone who is  new at this and is learning it on the go. If I am doing something wrong then please tell me what is wrong or reference a URL for me to read up on.

Comment: I'm not bashing, but you can't just remove code that you don't understand.  You put it in their originally (without understanding it) because you were following an example.  The questions I was asking you were diagnostic questions you should have been doing yourself.  If I'm asking you to do something, that means we're searching for diagnostic information.  That doesn't mean start removing lines of code you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Javascript pro, but as written:

```
NSString *js = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"script" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@"www" ];
[self.viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

I don't imagine this could ever possible work.

`pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:` returns a path to a file.  Again, I know almost nothing about Javascript, but I highly doubt a filepath is going to look like any Javascript at all.

```
NSString *js = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"script" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@"www" ];
NSLog(@"%@",js);
```

Try that snippet and look at what prints.  It'll print one of two things.  If the file was found, it will print the file path to that file.  If the fill was not found, it will print "(null)" (or something like this, as the `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:` method returns `nil` if the file is not found).

In order to get the contents of the file at the path, you need to make use of `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`, an `NSString` class method.